# Core data NSManagedObject convert to json format

Tags: core-data, swift4

Hi guys I need your help I am new in swift language now I Stuck here I need json like this format from core data result. thanks in advance

Core Data Function return this result and I want to convert this result info json format

```
func GetAttendance()->[Tbl_Attendance]
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tbl_Attendance")

        do {
            let fetchedAttendance = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Tbl_Attendance]
            return fetchedAttendance
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch Tbl_Attendance: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I need to convert like this

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "name": "Giuseppe",
            "lastName": "Lanza",
            "age": 31
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core data NSManagedObject convert into json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775145/core-data-nsmanagedobject-convert-into-json-format)

Comment: Improve your previous question instead of creating an exact duplicate of the same low quality.

Comment: i just delete previous question i need your help guys please guide me

Comment: But you haven’t improved it at all! You want to convert to json but how can anyone help you if you don’t tell us what to convert from? What is the definition of your core data entity?

Comment: thanks for reply yes i have core data database i am saving offline data in core data entity one table for attendance so i want to post on server through api so i just need to tbl_attendance result convert into json format so i will post json to api and you can you my function retrun value.

Comment: How is `Tbl_Attendance` related to `students`? If you want a concrete solution you have to give more information.  By the way ***T**a**bl**e* in terms of a database is tautologic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create extension to `Tbl_Attendance` and make it implement `Encodable`
- Create `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {...}` in extension containing all attributes to encode
- Implement `public func encode(to encoder: Encoder)` in extension
- From somewhere in your code perform encoding

Example

```
extension Tbl_Attendance: Encodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case prop1
    case prop2
  }

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(prop1, forKey: .prop1)
    try container.encode(prop2, forKey: .prop2)
  }
}

//perform encoding somewhere in your code
let arr: GetAttendance() 
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let json = try encoder.encode(arr)
    //print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print("JSON error \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Brother thank you so much really i appreciate your work. :) your function return me json but i need more your help

Comment: [{"id":"87BB1867-8FF4-4150-ADAF-64CD078A701A","employee_id":"EF5D995B-BB43-4CBD-9E81-FDCCFB068B78","business_id":"A8CFDDE3-DEC8-46AA-A7F8-03916A6F4F54","device_id":"30D0BB95-9951-468B-B748-DCF3C4A6DA14"}]

Comment: i need result like this .   {
    "Attendance": [
        {
            "id": "87BB1867-8FF4-4150-ADAF-64CD078A701A",
            "employee_id": "EF5D995B-BB43-4CBD-9E81-FDCCFB068B78",
            "business_id": "A8CFDDE3-DEC8-46AA-A7F8-03916A6F4F54",
            "device_id": "30D0BB95-9951-468B-B748-DCF3C4A6DA14"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @user3065304 I think I have given an adequate answer to your question, if you need further help you should post a new question with the proper information needed to help you.

Comment: brother i solved my problem but really thank you much. you are good person.